# Creating a PowerBI Timeline with Dates

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, timeline

So I have a large set of data which looks something like this:

| Column A | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Study 1 | 11-12-23 |
| Study 2 | 24-01-24 |
| Study 3 | 09-12-23 |
| Study 4 | 19-02-24 |

I want to create a timeline view in PowerBI, which will show which studies have which dates associated with them. Maybe a Gantt chart or something similar (I know there is only one date so maybe have a marker for a study instead of a bar)?

[image: EXAMPLE of wanted output]

I have also installed the visual 'timeline 2.4.0' but unsure how to make it display anything...

[image: This is what i've got so far...]

Any and all solutions or suggestions welcome :)

[image: This is what I get if I attempt the first solution...]

-- Answer below did not help. Not sure why the downvote, but I want an output like the one I have showed and still no resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Here my suggestion using costomer visual named "Dot Plot":

[image]

> See pbix file for details via this link:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to have it in months instead of actual dates (like my image attached) as there will be multiple studies per month and I would like each 'section/quadrant' to reflect a whole month?